# Java Changing Font For All Buttons

Tags: java, swing, button, fonts

My Program is using an immense amount of JButton's, I was wondering how I would be able to change the font of all existing buttons within a specific panel, without having to individually change the font for each button.

Comment: @Arvind The `UIManager` values will change the font for all `JButtons` in his program. The OP wants to change only those in a single `JPanel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering how I would be able to change the font of all existing
>   buttons within a specific panel, without having to individually change
>   the font for each button

Technically, you can't, you need to be able to iterate the container and change each button individually...

Assuming that all the buttons are on a single container (and not contained within multiple sub containers), you could simply iterate through all the components in the given container, test to see if they are a `JButton` and apply the new font.

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 48);
for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
    if (comp instanceof JButton) {
        ((JButton)comp).setFont(font);
    }
}
```

For example...

Comment: UIManager.put("Button.font", new Font(...)); - is simpler.

Comment: @IvanBabanin 1- That will change the font for ALL the buttons in the whole application, the OP specifically state *"existing buttons within a specific panel"*. 2- If the UI has already being created and visible, you'd also need to call `updateUI`, which doesn't always work well :P

Comment: @IvanBabanin No worries, that's the first thing that went through my head to

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've tried to implement it, by doing
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 48);
for (Component numbersP : getComponents()) {
    if (comp instanceof JButton) {
        ((JButton)numbersP).setFont(font);
    }
}
Where numbersP is my Panel where the buttons are, but I am getting a symbol not found error

Comment: @Corjava Use `for (Component comp : numbersP.getComponents())` instead

Comment: hmm, no more error but it doesn't seem to be changing the fonts, could it be because this specific panel is nested within another?

Comment: Does `numbersP` contain the actual buttons?  If it does, you may need to call `numbersP.revalidate` in order to get the buttons to update

Comment: Yes, numbersP contains the buttons, where would I call revalidate?

Comment: At the end of the loop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51648/discussion-between-corjava-and-madprogrammer)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class extending `JButton` and set the font for that class, then use it for all the buttons in the `JPanel`:

```
class MyJButton extends JButton {

    MyJButton() {

        super();
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
   }
}
```

You can override whichever constructor you are using.

Comment: What would the syntax for the setFont function looks like this?
    
    setFont(Font,"Arial",Font.BOLD, 40);

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would be

```
setFont(new Font("fontName", fontStyle, fontSize));
```

Unless you have a custom font you made, then it would be

```
setFont(font);
```

Comment: Sorry on my phone right now. Autocorrect is having a field day with the auto capitalization.