# How can I run a code for multiple JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcomponent

I want run a code for JButtons I want.

I search for this in Internet but I can't find a solution for swing applications.

```
b1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
b2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
b3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
b4.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
b5.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
b6.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
b7.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
b8.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
b9.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
```

I tried below code but I could not use JButton properties

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[];
```

I declare it

```
buttons[0] = b1;
buttons[1] = b2;
buttons[2] = b3;
buttons[3] = b4;
buttons[4] = b5;
buttons[5] = b6;
buttons[6] = b7;
buttons[7] = b8;
buttons[8] = b9;
```

But this didn't work:

```
buttons.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
```

Comment: iterate over a list/collection/array/... containing your buttons and preform the action on each iterated element

Comment: If you want to change the font for all of the buttons you have, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23357142/java-changing-font-for-all-buttons

Comment: @Stultuske This isn't work.

Comment: @Arnaud I want run command for JButtons I want

Comment: @Matrix4290 I hope you understand that "This isn't work" is meaningless. what have you tried? what didn't work? did you get unexpected behaviour? did you get an error message?

Comment: One line, probably not but, you could use an array or `List` to store or the button references and simply loop over them

Comment: @Stultuske I searched all of your advices but I didn't get any of the results I wanted.

Comment: @MadProgrammer These don't working. Example I use Arrays but I can't use JButton properties

Comment: @Matrix4290 and without you showing us what you tried, we will never figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: @Matrix4290 I would highly recommend that you go back and read through [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) - [as a concrete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814566/array-that-holds-jbutton-objects)

Comment: @Stultuske I added the code

Comment: @Matrix4290 seriously. just showing us the array, not showing where you declared it, where you tried to use it or how you tried to use it ... still not nearly enough

Comment: @Stultuske Is that enough?

Comment: of course the way you do it doesn't work. firstly, you put the buttons two times in the array. why? secondly: don't call the setFont method on the array itself, but on the elements in it, while you are iterating over the array.

Comment: @Stultuske No meaning. I wrote this code to don't write again.

Comment: @Matrix4290 I posted an answer with how you should have tried it, look at that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: You create an array, and fill it with the buttons.

```
JButton[] buttons = {b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9};
```

Note: this already fills the array with the buttons, so statements like this:

```
buttons[0] = b1;
buttons[1] = b2;
buttons[2] = b3;
```

are redundant.

Step 2: Iterate over the array

```
for ( JButton button : buttons ) {
  // here you are to call the setFont
}
```

Step 3: Set the font

```
for ( JButton button : buttons ) {
  button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, (h / 25)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to keep the button as fields or in a structure **AND** the buttons are in one container (if they are in a different container, you will have to do more), another approach would be to use [Darryl Burke's SwingUtils class](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/).

So let's see how easier it would be:

```
for (JButton b : SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfClass(JButton.class, panelWithButtons)) {
    b.setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,14));
}
```

Voilà! All buttons in "panelWithButtons" JPanel has this font. No fields kept, no array kept.

Comment: This is good method, but in my opinion array is easy than this.

Comment: @Matrix4290 I find it more elegant.